# Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2 Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

I'm getting this error message whenever I try to compile my xcode project, I've been around searching and applying answers from other related questions, and still not able to solve the issue, so I post this specific question. How can I fix this?

```
ProcessPCH "/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Project Name-Prefix-dyzfahcpvwmwmcbbcszxksgksawt/Project Name-Prefix.pch.pth" "Company/Project Name-Prefix.pch" normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd "/Users/ObsidianSword/Dropbox/ProjectName - iOS Projects Folder/Official Projects/Project Name (Company 3.3.3.2)"
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -iquote "/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/ProjectName-generated-files.hmap" "-I/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/ProjectName-own-target-headers.hmap" "-I/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/ProjectName-all-target-headers.hmap" -iquote "/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/ProjectName-project-headers.hmap" -I/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/ChristianD/Applications/link_os_sdk/iOS/v1.1.5266/lib/include -I/Users/ObsidianSword/Dropbox/Company -I- -IiOS -IProjects -IFolder/Official -IProjects/Project -ISolution "-I(Company" "-I3.3.3.2)/../ReaderAPI-iOS-0.7/ReaderAPI-iOS-0.7" -I/Users/ObsidianSword/Dropbox/Company -I- -IiOS -IProjects -IFolder/Official -IProjects/Open -ISolution "-I(Company" "-I3.3.3.2)/../ReaderAPI-iOS-1.0/ReaderAPI-iOS-1.0" -I/Users/ObsidianSword/Dropbox/Company -I- -IiOS -IProjects -IFolder/Official -IProjects/Open -ISolution "-I(Company" "-I3.3.3.2)/Company/lib/include" "-I/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/DerivedSources/i386" "-I/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/ProjectName.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ProjectName.build/DerivedSources" -F/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 --serialize-diagnostics "/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/ProjectName-Prefix-dyzfahcpvwmwmcbbcszxksgksawt/ProjectName-Prefix.pch.dia" -c "/Users/ObsidianSword/Dropbox/Company - iOS Projects Folder/Official Projects/Project Name (Company 3.3.3.2)/Company/Project Name-Prefix.pch" -o "/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/ProjectName-Prefix-dyzfahcpvwmwmcbbcszxksgksawt/ProjectName-Prefix.pch.pth" -MMD -MT dependencies -MF "/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project Name-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Project Name-Prefix-dyzfahcpvwmwmcbbcszxksgksawt/Project Name-Prefix.pch.d"
clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: this line is what's bothering me:
 clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead Command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this has something to do with my libraries compiling version.
For anyone who has the same problem or close to this problem, please make sure you got the lastest libraries from your device's manufacturers.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is getting LLVM compiler 4.2 error and for whom above solution did not work, Try clean+build or restart XCode / Mac. In my case restarting Xcode did not work but restarting Mac fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i seen the crash log. 
I think you have set a wrong library path with '-I'

```
-I/Users/ObsidianSword/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bkinddajwtvxeybjhjlenxyuhuxu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
```

as you can see it at the staring of the path, which is not supported by Apple LLVM Compiler.
Fix it and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: My Header and Library Search Path in the Targets Project Settings does not have this "-I" thing on it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious:

```
-I/Users/ObsidianSword/Dropbox/Company -I- -IiOS -IProjects -IFolder/Official -IProjects/Project -ISolution "-I(Company" "-I3.3.3.2)/../ReaderAPI-iOS-0.7/ReaderAPI-iOS-0.7"
```

It looks like you have an include path that really should just be

```
-I"/Users/ObsidianSword/Dropbox/Company - iOS Projects Folder/Official Projects/ProjectName (Company 3.3.3.2)/../ReaderAPI-iOS-0.7/ReaderAPI-iOS-0.7"
```

or something similar, but it is probably missing quotes to account for the spaces in the file path. I would look for something like that in your Xcode project settings and wrap the full path in quotes.